# How can I start testing my Google Drive UI integration?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, manifest, google-apps-marketplace

I started developing a Google Drive UI integration, and I am having a rather basic problem. I cannot find the option to start testing my integration.

I have done the following so far:

- I created a new project in Google API console (https://console.developers.google.com/).
- I enabled "G Suite Marketplace SDK" and "Google Drive API" services for this project.
- I create an Oauth consent screen and set up credentials.

What else do I have to do to get my integration to show up in the Google Drive? I can add published public add-ons to my Google Drive, but for some reason I am unable to start using my new project. Where can I find it?

Comment: If you have followed the [Drive UI integration overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-apps) your Application should be usable through the **New** button or **Open With** Buton or **Right Click on your drive > More > Connect More Apps > Hamburguer menu > DOMAIN Apps**

Comment: Yes. I have followed the Drive UI integration overview. Please note that I do not have Domain Apps option, as I do not have a GSuite account. I am developing an add-on that is supposed to be for all users (not only for paid users of GSuite).

Comment: Since you said that you're trying to install an add-on can you please confirm if the Apps script used is a standalone project and it has a trigger like **onEdit**, **onOpen** in order to reflect your code. Also check if you can see your Project in your drive **Settings > Manage Apps > YourAddon**. It'll be helpful if you share a sanitized snippet of code for getting more context.

Comment: We do not have any scripts related to our Google Drive add-on. It is an add-on that simply opens a document in our web app.

We opened a trial G Suite account with domain, and copied our add-on there. There, we can see it under Domain Apps. So, we believe that the add-on is properly configured on our non-G Suite account (without domain), but for some reason it doesn't show up in the store for our development account. What else can we check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

There are [two types of add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview#types_of_add-ons):

- [Google Workspace Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types#add-ons)
- [Editor Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types#editor_add-ons)

Since your add-on is `an add-on that simply opens a document in our web app` you are looking for a **Workspace Add-on** so in order to manually install your add-on without using a G-Suite Domain. You should deploy your Apps Script project from manifest as mentioned in this [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/cats-quickstart).

Keep in mind that the previous quickstart is following the Legacy Apps Script Editor. This example has a manifest file example `appsscript.json` which looks like:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"],
  "runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Cats",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "universalActions": [{
        "label": "Learn more about Cataas",
        "openLink": "https://cataas.com"
      }]
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [{
        "unconditional": {
        },
        "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
      }],
      "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [{
          "text": "Insert cat",
          "runFunction": "onGmailCompose"
        }],
        "draftAccess": "NONE"
      }
    },
    "drive": {
      "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDriveItemsSelected"
      }
    },
    "calendar": {
      "eventOpenTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarEventOpen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where **oauthScopes** will request permissions for each application, **addOns.common** will define the common parameters for all of the services defined below, like **addOns.drive**. In the Drive service you will see the **onItemsSelectedTrigger** which will handle the event of selecting an item and it will run the **onDriveItemsSelected** function previously defined in the Quickstart example. You can see all the event triggers related [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers#manifest_triggers).

Once you installed your add-on it will be shown in the UI of each service **defined in your manifest**. Keep in mind this is just a self installation tutorial, you should follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview) in order to publish your add-on so another one is able to install it.