# How to test Google Drive UI Integration "New" and "Open With"?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

My question is exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281481/how-can-i-start-testing-my-google-drive-ui-integration) but I think I am missing something because I can't seem to follow the marked answer. So to clear things up:

- I have a GCP project, `my-drive-project` that has [configured Drive UI integration](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-sdk), setting "Open with" url to my website https://www.example.com/open-drive (there is also New Url but I think it's similar).
- My website at https://www.example.com/open-drive has Javascript code to read `state` parameter as per [Handle a New URL](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/integrate-create) and [Handle an Open URL](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/integrate-open).

Now how do I test my website to make sure the code at https://www.example.com/open-drive is correct? How do I get the "Open With" menu in my Drive?

As I understand I need to somehow install an unpublished Google Workspace App, but how do I do that? In this case, clearly I am not using any App Script so the answer in the linked question confuses me greatly.

I found out [Alternate Runtime](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes?hl=en_US) but the `deployment.json` doc confuses me as well as I cannot find any information on how to fill it in. I took the sample JSON there, delete all services but `drive`, tried Installing it but I do not see the menu anywhere. Also I believe this is for an add-on app which *I think my app is not* (because the website simply receive a request and process it, not modifying any UI of Drive). Below is my current config:

```json
{
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "My App",
      "logoUrl": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/googlematerialicons/markunread_mailbox/v6/black-24dp/1x/gm_markunread_mailbox_black_24dp.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "https://www.example.com"
      }
    },
    "drive": {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that from your page `https://example.com`, if you request `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install` scope, the app get installed and you get the menu from Google Drive.

So the scope should be something like this (space-delimited):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
```

I didn't have `drive.install` scope before.

---

Previous answer:

As a temporary workaround, I wrote this web page to simulate the `state` parameter: https://datvm.github.io/DriveUiIntegrationTest/. The repo source code and documentation is here: https://github.com/datvm/DriveUiIntegrationTest.

Basically it uses Picker API to grant permission of files or a folder to your app and then redirect to the app URL with documented `state` parameter:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just tested Google Drive UI Integration blind, like [@Luke Vo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653457/luke-vo). It is still not listed / approved in the Workspace Marketplace. However I just noticed the integration in Google Drive under the account I used for testing.

My guess it, what is required for testing:

1. configured Drive UI integration
2. run your oauth flow once with scopes for 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
3. **wait...** the docs mention regarding icons *"Icons can take up to 24 hours to appear in Drive"* So I assume it may take a few hours for changes to propagate through the system.

I only noticed it days later when I was ready to submit it to the Workspace Marketplace. For good measure you may also wanna pre-fill all the Workspace Marketplace details to the point that you could hit submit any time.

Comment: Interesting, your third point makes sense! I keep getting rejected and they say my graphical assets (all 3: icons, banners and screenshots) failed. Next time I will wait 24 hours before submitting the Workspace listing.